# after logeed in using php session , how to select all the other users?

Tags: php

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("db");
session_start();
ob_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
header("location:login.php");
}
$res = mysql_query("select * from usertable");
$vals = mysql_fetch_row($res);
foreach($vals as $k) {
  echo "$k";
}
```

here after logged in , i want to select all the users, so that in my search engine it will come. But i am not able to do that.. How to see all other users here so that i can go to their profile and give add as a friend.I dont want to use any facebook sdk api. By just simple database management.

Comment: What is the error? Is it working or not? Syntactically it is correct.

Comment: It is giving only logged in user's information and not others @ Yogesh

Comment: It is already getting all users. What else do you want?

Comment: user the SQL as `select * from usertable where username != $_SESSION["username"]`. !! this is vulnerable to sql injections :)

Comment: @AlphaMale is right. `select * from usertable` query will give you all users.

Comment: @Yogesh , no , it is giving only logged in user

Comment: @SSS in which table all your userdata present?

Comment: usertable itself. . no no it is displaying only first row .. Am i wrong with mysql_fetch_row or foreach ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store in one of your tables each successful login (each user session).

Then you can retrieve it with a query.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line

```
$vals = mysql_fetch_row($res);
```

to

```
$vals = mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

**And please stop using mysql_* functions start using mysqli_*

Answer (score 1):

I got correct answer after changing my code like ,

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from usertable ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $row['username']=$row['name'];
  echo "$row";
  $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}

echo json_encode($row_set);
```

Thanks for all the response i got. .

Comment: Credit goes to Deepak!

Answer (score 0):

why not add a field in your table of users like active. And when the user logs in change the value to 1 and when the user logs out change the value to 0. So you can easily query the logged in users. like in your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT user FROM users_table WHERE active = '1' ";
```

in that case, it will give you a list of users who are currently logged in.